# Error when trying to run Fluent NHibernate tutorial example

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have downloaded the Fluent NHibernate source distribution, compiled all projects in solution and then run Examples.FirstProject. Exception occur in FluentConfiguration.cs in method BuildSessionFactory(): An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. What shall I do to avoid this exception?

PS I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508478/runtime-error-when-trying-to-run-fluent-nhibernate-tutorial-example) post but its not help me

Edit:
**Exception Message**   "The following types may not be used as proxies:\nExamples.FirstProject.Entities.Employee: method set_Id should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'\nExamples.FirstProject.Entities.Product: method set_Id should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'\nExamples.FirstProject.Entities.Store: method set_Id should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'"    string

**Exception Source:** "NHibernate"

**Exception StackTrace:**
        StackTrace  "   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ValidateEntities() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1051\r\n   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Validate() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 958\r\n   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line 1250\r\n   at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in C:\_WorkProjects\_nHibernate\jagregory-fluent-nhibernate-c24de5a\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:line 231" string

Comment: I don't know the tutorial project in question, but this exception can have a lot of different root causes. Usually a better error description is available in the InnerException

Comment: You need to post the full exception and we can go from there.  Use Exception.ToString() and post that here.

Comment: Jonas H, what is "InnerException"? Fields of exception instance?

Comment: Also when you posting question about mapping an entity it helps to peps if you add entity and your mapping as code :) so you know

Comment: @cpoDesign Thanks I do so next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to (Examples.FirstProject -> Entities -> and in (Employee.cs, Product.cs, and Store.cs)

Change the Id property from:

```
public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
```

To:

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type, Examples.FirstProject.Entities.Employee should have the ID property set to

```
public virtual int ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Windman Did you make ALL properties of ALL mapped entities virtual?

Comment: I've downloaded wrong source files from https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate (just click Download button) When I get it from official site http://fluentnhibernate.org/ (only dll files) and add to my project everything works fine!